# rewrite error in url with using @ sign in emails

Tags: .htaccess

in my .htaccess i do rewrite the domain.nl into domain.nl/nl/

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.nl
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.nl
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
#For every other language (including English :)) use Dutch
RewriteRule ^$ /nl/home/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /nl/home/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I get a problem when using an unsubscribe for my customers:

https://www.domain.nl/nl/uitschrijven/?email=test@domain.nl

is also rewrite and the @ sign is deleted. Result is:

https://www.domain.nl/nl/uitschrijven/?email=testdomain.nl

What to do to fix this rewrite and let the @ where it belongs?

Comment: Is the rule in htaccess file or server config?

Comment: in .htacces file of the site

Comment: Change the last rule to: `RewriteRule ^((?!nl/).*)$ /nl/home/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: It still delete the @ sign from the url. here the rows:
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.nl
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.nl/$1 [R=301,L] 
 RewriteRule ^$ /nl/home/ [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /nl/home/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^((?!nl/).*)$ /nl/home/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: There might be some other issue, but try using the `NE` flag to send it as is. `[L,NE,R=301]`

Comment: By the first action the @ is deleted. When paste a copy of the url again and start it... the @ is not deleted! It is a WP CMS I use. have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: [L,NE,R=301] did not solve the problem. When past the url for the first time @ is deleted. When past the url a second time... the @ is NOT deleted. Hope someone of you understands what to do to solve this. Oh.. my sites has a WP CMS.

Comment: I don't know if that is an apache problem.